# Resize image before send to the firebase

Tags: android, image, firebase

I have this code below, I want to reduce the image quality originated from the camera or gallery before sending to Firebase.
The path (Uri) of the image is being sent, how can I implement a code here?

How can I do it?
........................................................................................................................................

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST || requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

        }
    }
}




public String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}

private void uploadFile() {
    //checking if file is available
    if (filePath != null && (editTextName.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                && (editTextName1.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                && (editTextName2.getText().toString().length() > 0)
               ) {


            //displaying progress dialog while image is uploading
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            progressDialog.show();

            //getting the storage reference
            StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child(Constants.STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(filePath));

        //adding the file to reference
        sRef.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //dismissing the progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        //displaying success toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowMap.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        //creating the upload object to store uploaded image details
                        Upload upload = new Upload(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(), editTextName1.getText().toString().trim(), editTextName2.getText().toString().trim(), editTextLatitude.getText().toString().trim(), editTextLongitude.getText().toString().trim(), taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());

                        //adding an upload to firebase database
                        String uploadId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                        mDatabase.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);



                    }
                })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            //displaying the upload progress
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                        }
                    });
         }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }  //display an error if no file is selected

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve!

Resize image

```
 private String storeImage(Bitmap image) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("log",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("log", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("log", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/Files");

        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        String mImageName="MI_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        Log.v("log", "save:  " + mediaStorageDir.getAbsoluteFile());
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST || requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                storeImage(bitmap);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Log.v("log", "path = " + getOutputMediaFile().getAbsoluteFile());
                imagemfinal = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile().getAbsoluteFile());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                storeImage(bitmap1);
                imagemfinal = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile().getAbsoluteFile());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
img.setImageBitmap(image2);
String incident_ID = IncidentFormActivity.incident_id;

imagepath="/sdcard/RDMS/"+incident_ID+ x + ".PNG";
File file = new File(imagepath);
    try {
        double xFactor = 0;
        double width = Double.valueOf(image2.getWidth());
        Log.v("WIDTH", String.valueOf(width));
        double height = Double.valueOf(image2.getHeight());
        Log.v("height", String.valueOf(height));
        if(width>height){
        xFactor = 841/width;
    }
    else{
        xFactor = 595/width;
    }


Log.v("Nheight", String.valueOf(width*xFactor));
Log.v("Nweight", String.valueOf(height*xFactor));
int Nheight = (int) ((xFactor*height));
int NWidth =(int) (xFactor * width) ; 

bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( image2,NWidth, Nheight, true);
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
ostream.close();
```

This is the code for resizing the images..

Answer (score 0):

check this class. This is helpful to compress image

```
class ImageFile(val uri: Uri, name: String) {

    val filename: String

    init {
        val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Documents")
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs()
        }
        val fileNoMedia = File(file.absolutePath + "/.nomedia")
        if (!fileNoMedia.exists())
            fileNoMedia.createNewFile()
        if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            filename = file.absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf"
        } else {
            filename = file.absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun copyFileStream(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
        if (filename.endsWith(".pdf") || filename.endsWith(".PDF")) {
            var ins: InputStream? = null
            var os: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
                os = FileOutputStream(filename)
                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var length: Int = ins.read(buffer)
                while (length > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    length = ins.read(buffer)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ins?.close()
                os?.close()
            }
        } else {
            var ins: InputStream? = null
            var os: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
                var scaledBitmap: Bitmap? = null
                val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
                var bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins, null, options)
                var actualHeight = options.outHeight
                var actualWidth = options.outWidth

                //      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612
                val maxHeight = 816.0f
                val maxWidth = 612.0f
                var imgRatio = (actualWidth / actualHeight).toFloat()
                val maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight

                //      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image
                if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
                    if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                        imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
                        actualWidth = (imgRatio * actualWidth).toInt()
                        actualHeight = maxHeight.toInt()
                    } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                        imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
                        actualHeight = (imgRatio * actualHeight).toInt()
                        actualWidth = maxWidth.toInt()
                    } else {
                        actualHeight = maxHeight.toInt()
                        actualWidth = maxWidth.toInt()

                    }
                }

                //      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight)

                //      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false

                //      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
                options.inPurgeable = true
                options.inInputShareable = true
                options.inTempStorage = ByteArray(16 * 1024)


                try {
                    //          load the bitmap from its path
                    ins.close()
                    ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins, null, options)
                } catch (exception: OutOfMemoryError) {
                    exception.printStackTrace()

                }

                try {
                    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                } catch (exception: OutOfMemoryError) {
                    exception.printStackTrace()
                }

                val ratioX = actualWidth / options.outWidth.toFloat()
                val ratioY = actualHeight / options.outHeight.toFloat()
                val middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f
                val middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f

                val scaleMatrix = Matrix()
                scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY)

                val canvas = Canvas(scaledBitmap!!)
                canvas.matrix = scaleMatrix
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.width / 2, middleY - bmp.height / 2, Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG))

                os = FileOutputStream(filename)
                scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, os)
                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var length: Int = ins.read(buffer)
                while (length > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    length = ins.read(buffer)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ins?.close()
                os?.close()
            }
        }
        return filename
    }

    fun calculateInSampleSize(options: BitmapFactory.Options, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Int {
        val height = options.outHeight
        val width = options.outWidth
        var inSampleSize = 1
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            val heightRatio = Math.round(height.toFloat() / reqHeight.toFloat())
            val widthRatio = Math.round(width.toFloat() / reqWidth.toFloat())
            inSampleSize = if (heightRatio < widthRatio) heightRatio else widthRatio
        }
        val totalPixels = (width * height).toFloat()
        val totalReqPixelsCap = (reqWidth * reqHeight * 2).toFloat()
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++
        }

        return inSampleSize
    }
}
```

for more please visit [this link](https://lalitjadav007.blogspot.in/2017/08/compress-image-in-android.html)